# Saving Multiple graphs in 1 pdf page from a for loop in R

Tags: r, pdf, for-loop, ggplot2, gridextra

Please assume any dataset. Situation: I am running a for loop on the all independent variables to create a relationship(scatter) plot with the dependent variable. And want to save the plots as a pdf but in 1 or 2 pages of pdf for 1 file, instead of every graph in 1 individual page(that I already achieved). I am using following cases

1st Try using dev option

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

pdf("one.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(dataset)) 
{
new_plot[[i]]=print(ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=dataset[[i]], y=loss))+geom_point(size=1, alpha=0.3)+ 
      geom_smooth(method = lm)+
      xlab(paste0(colnames(int[i]), '\n', 'R-Squared: ',round(cor(int[[i]],int$loss, use = 'complete.obs'), 2)))+
      ylab("log(loss)") + theme_light())
plot_list = c(new_plot[[i]])
grid.arrange(plot_list)
}
dev.off()
```

2nd Try using ggsave

```
    for (i in 1:length(dataset)) 
    {
    new_plot[[i]]=print(ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=dataset[[i]], y=loss))+geom_point(size=1, alpha=0.3)+ 
          geom_smooth(method = lm)+
          xlab(paste0(colnames(int[i]), '\n', 'R-Squared: ',round(cor(int[[i]],int$loss, use = 'complete.obs'), 2)))+
          ylab("log(loss)") + theme_light())
    m=marrangeGrob(new_plot[[i]],nrow=2, ncol=2)
    }

    ggsave("one.pdf",m)
```

Both of the time I received an error

```
Error in gList(data = list(list(x = c(2213.18, 1283.6, 3005.09, 939.85,  : 
only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

Also if possible then share how the graphs can be posted in 2*2(example) on every page. I do appreciate all the help.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach might be to convert the data to long form (using `gather` from `tidyr`) then just use `facet_wrap` to do the arranging for you. This also saves on some of the difficult looping and automates the inclusion of any legends you may need/want.

Because you didn't give any reproducible data, here ia an example with the builtin `iris` data.

```
iris %>%
  gather(Response, Value, -Sepal.Width, -Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Value
             , y = Sepal.Width
             , col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_wrap(~Response
             , scale = "free_x")
```

gives:

[image]

If, for some reason, you really want to loop through the plots instead, you can use the package `cowplot` to stitch things together. One of the issues in your approach above is that you seem to be over-writing the plot list each time, when you may be better off constructing all of the plots, then handling them.

Here, I am using `lapply` instead of `for` as it tends to work much more smoothly. I am also using `aes_string` instead of passing a vector to `aes` as that makes it more clear what is happening where.

```
myPlots <- lapply(names(iris)[c(1,3,4)], function(thisPredictor){
  iris %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = thisPredictor
                      , y = "Sepal.Width"
                      , col = "Species")) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
})
```

Then, you can use `plot_grid` to put them together like so

```
plot_grid(plotlist = myPlots)
```

gives:

[image]

which would work if not for the legends. Luckily, those can be easily handled as well

```
plot_grid(
  plot_grid(plotlist = lapply(myPlots, function(x){x + theme(legend.position = "none")})
            , nrow = 1)
  , get_legend(myPlots[[1]] + theme(legend.direction = "horizontal"))
  , nrow = 2
  , rel_heights = c(9,1) )
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helpful. Can you also tell me how can I take y= log(y) while using aes_string in same solution, because of "thispredictor" passed as x, I have to use aes_string

Comment: You should just be able to type it in the same way you would, just inside quotes. In my example, you would just use `y = "log(Sepal.Width)"`. You can also use paste (or other functions that return a character vector) to add functions, e.g., `paste0("log(",thisPredictor, ")")`